# How to disable caching?

Tags: date-preferences, caching

I am working on an issue regarding Date Formats (`Localization > Date Formats`) and it took me a while to realize it is caching due to which changes in `Localization.settings.php` file were not being reflected. Even after the realization, after every small change I have to clear the cache manually. I used *drush* (`$ drush cc civicrm`) to do it which takes about a minute everytime and it is hectic.

So, how can I disable caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching methods can be enabled or disabled in your CiviCRM settings file (eg: civicrm.settings.php).

The setting you're looking for is:
CIVICRM_DB_CACHE_CLASS

To disable caching, change the value to 'NoCache'. Other possible settings are documented above the setting in the file.

There is a page about caching in the documentation here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Cache+Reference